# Show $Σ^{-1} = λ_{1}^{−1}uu^T + λ_{2}^{−1}vv^T$ for positive definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

The question is: Let $u$ be a unit length eigenvector of $Σ$ associated with the eigenvalue $λ_1$. Let $v$ be a unit length eigenvector of $Σ$ orthogonal to $u$ that is associated with the eigenvalue $λ_2$. Show that $Σ^{-1} = λ_{1}^{−1}uu^T + λ_{2}^{−1}vv^T$ holds. You need to show this for general positive definite symmetric Σ.

I expressed Σ as $ADA^{-1}$ where A is the matrix of eigenvectors and D of the eigenvectors. I'm not sure if this is the right way to approach this.

Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: I assume that the matrices considered here are $2 \times 2$. Given any orthonormal basis $(u,v)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and given two real numbers $\alpha,\beta$, the matrix $\alpha u u^\top + \beta v v^\top$ is the matrix in the canonical basis of the endomorphism which sends $u$ on $\alpha u$ and  $v$ on $\beta v$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\Sigma$ is $2 \times 2$, otherwise the question does not make sense.

If $A$ has $u$ and $v$ as columns, and $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, then $\Sigma=ADA^{-1}$ (where $A^{-1} = A^\top$ since $A$ is orthogonal). Check that $\Sigma^{-1} = AD^{-1} A^{-1}$, and then rewrite this in terms of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, u, v$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why the inverse of A is its transpose? I'm not sure what it means for a matrix to be orthogonal.

Comment: @user898975 Use the assumptions about $u$ and $v$ to show that $A^\top A = I$.